# Recodificar una variable en r

Tags: r, variables

Le metí inicialmente una base de datos a un lm para realizar una regresión, pero esta la cree en una función y luego cree una función para predecir con predict, los argumentos que le meto a esta función son: un vector con la misma estructura de la data inicial (Lo guardo como un data frame y luego lo exporto como un archivo .csv) y la regresión, pero al hacer uso de la función me dice que las variables tienen diferente tipo, como hago para que estas permanezcan con el tipo de variable inicial??

```
predecir=function(x,regresion){
    xx=read.csv2(x,sep=";",header=TRUE,dec = ",",fill=TRUE)
    columns_to_change <- c(25,49:52,54:63,76)
    dat[,columns_to_change]<- lapply(dat[,columns_to_change], as.factor)
    xx<-data.frame(xx)

    load(url(regresion))

    basef1<-as.data.frame(xx[,resultado[[5]][!is.na(resultado[[5]])]]) 
    colnames(basef1)<-resultado[[5]][!is.na(resultado[[5]])] 
    prediccion=predict(resultado[[1]],newdata=basef1,interval="predict",level=0.95,na.rm=FALSE)

    library(xtable)
    newobject<-xtable(prediccion)
    print.xtable(newobject, type="html",file="resultadot1.html")
    return(prediccion)
}
```

Esta es la función que estoy usando para predecir, el archivo que se mete como argumento, me cambia el tipo de variable que inicialmente tenia, por ejemplo si la tenia factor al crear el nuevo archivo ya no me la toma como factor, eso es lo que necesito conservar los tipos de las variables.

Comment: Bienvenida Laura, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] así también como crear un [mcve]. Con respecto a tu pregunta, es muy difícil darte una respuesta si no muestras el código del que estás hablando, te sugiero que edites la pregunta y agregues la mínima porción de código que permita comprender el problema.

Comment: O también me sirve como comparar los tipos de las variables de dos bases de datos para saber si son iguales o diferentes y asignarle cualquiera de los dos tipos.

Comment: Laura, cual es la variable que está siendo modificada?  `dat`, `xx`, `basef1`?

Comment: La variable xx, es el data frame que yo le meto a la función para que me prediga (esa es la variable)

Comment: xx es un archivo en .csv, pero necesito que las variables queden con el tipo de una base de datos inicial que incluyo dentro de otra función

Comment: Laura, veamos: al principio asignas `xx <- read.csv2(...`, esto lee un csv y retorna un `data.frame`, por lo que si `xx` ya tenía una estructura eventualmente esto podría estar modificandola, luego no veo otra cosa rara, la única operación posterior que  podría modificar el valor de esta variable es `xx<-data.frame(xx)` que tiene poco sentido por que `xx` ya es un `data.frame`, pero más allá de eso, entiendo que no debería modificar la naturaleza original de `xx`. Te sugiero que antes  y después de invocar la función hagas un `str(xx)` y si puede postees la salida.

Comment: Dentro de una función anterior yo realizo este procedimiento (http://dat=read.csv2(data,sep=";",header=TRUE,dec = ",",fill=TRUE)
  apply.factor <- sapply(dat, function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(levels(as.factor(x)),as.vector(as.factor(c("0", "1"))))))
  col.to.factor <- seq(length(apply.factor))[apply.factor]
  dat[col.to.factor] <- lapply(dat[col.to.factor], as.factor).com) y exporto un Csv (xx) que contiene una sola fila y todas las columnas de la data que son los valores que quiero predecir y esta la meto en otra función que es predecir (la que esta en el ejemplo de la pregunta)

Comment: lo que quiero es que las variables del archivo xx tengan la misma estructura del archivo dat (mostrado en el ultimo comentario)